# pyspark GBTRegressor object has no attribute 'transform' after loading model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have been sent a pre-trained pyspark model (GBTRegressor) and I'm unable to use it on a dataset to get predictions. I have seen some posts about using Pipeline vs PipelineModel, but in this case it's just the regressor object and I can't load it with PipelineModel.

I'm able to successfully load the model with:

```
model = GTBRegressor.load(model_path)
type(model)
'pyspark.ml.regression.GBTRegressor'
```

but when I call `model.transform(test_df)` I get

```
AttributeError: 'GBTRegressor' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

I've tried putting model object in a Pipeline and PipelineModel, but nothing works. I also saw this class in the source code:

```
class GBTRegressionModel(TreeEnsembleModels):
    """
    Model fitted by GBTRegressor.

    .. versionadded:: 1.4.0
    """
```

but I can't load the model in using `GBTRegressionModel.load(model_path)`

If anyone can take the time to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here, it would be enormously appreciated! It took an entire week to run and I would like to avoid doing it again. Let me know if more info is needed from me to diagnose the issue.

Comment: why you can't load the model using `GBTRegressionModel.load(model_path)`?

Comment: I get the error: ```IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GBTRegressionModel but found class name org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GBTRegressor```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer is that because of a bug in the code, the untrained GBTRegressor object was saved instead of the trained one, thus it not having a transform attribute.